# Terminal not working correctly inside external NTFS drive High Sierra

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, high-sierra, ntfs

I would like to write to my NTFS drive that I used to use with a Windows computer. This Hard drive is an external portable hard drive.

I have tried to follow [this](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/) tutorial:

and have read this post:

[Cannot edit /etc/fstab to let NTFS drives write](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116022/cannot-edit-etc-fstab-to-let-ntfs-drives-write)

I have managed to create a new folder using the GUI, but if I use a terminal and cd into the drive, and type

`ls`

I get

`ls: .: No such file or directory`

What does this mean?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you edit the question and specify the output of `pwd` command?

Comment: @NimeshNeema the output of pwd is ```/Volumes/DRIVENAME```

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I just clarify that you actually still need this external drive to be in the NTFS format? That is, since you *used to use it with a Windows computer* does that mean you no longer intend to? If not, is there any reason not to reformat it into a native macOS compatible format?

Comment: @Monomeeth thanks for your help! I have content on there that I would like to use on my Mac like music that I saved on my old windows computer to this hard drive and don't want to loose this information :)

Comment: @apollowebdesigns As any aside, a significant number of the questions we get here are from users who have lost data and had no backups! So, I'm sure you've heard this before, but if you don't want to lose this info you should really invest in another hard drive for backup purposes. :)

Comment: @Monomeeth thanks for the advice. The data is important on the drive but if I loose it I loose it - it's my own responsibility. But thanks for the suggestion of a spare hard drive :)